# Pandas groupby and find row count difference where values of columns are interchanged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group this datafarme by col A and B and find the difference between the count where value of column B is column A and vice-versa.

**Dataframe:**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 112 | 456 |
| 112 | 456 |
| 112 | 456 |
| 456 | 112 |
| 456 | 112 |
| 113 | 457 |
| 113 | 457 |
| 457 | 113 |
| 457 | 113 |

**GroupBy Table:**

| A | B | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 456 | 3 |
| 456 | 112 | 2 |
| 113 | 457 | 2 |
| 457 | 113 | 2 |

Now Using this groupby table I want to compute the difference where colB == colA and colA == colB. Not sure how to get this expected result from the groupby table above

**Expected Result:**

| A | B | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 456 | 1 |
| 113 | 457 | 0 |

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve very well. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ignacioct Added details, does it make sense now?

Comment: yes! I will give it a thought

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a solution, but it is Python programming and it does not use a lot of Pandas tricks. Maybe somebody knows how to do it with Pandas magic and it is much more efficient. But, here goes my two cents:

First of all, I've reproduced your scenario:

```
columnA = [112, 112, 112, 456, 456, 113, 113, 457, 457]
columnB = [456, 456, 456, 112, 112, 457, 457, 113, 113]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["A"] = columnA
df["B"] = columnB

groupByTable = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()

groupByTable
```

Afterwards, the idea is to iterate through the rows of this dataframe, and if we find a tuple (A,B), and we had previously found the tuple (B,A), we compute the difference and save it in a dictionary. Finally, this dictionary is converted in a dataframe.

```
# Create a dictionary to know which elements has been visited
previousElements = {}

# And a dictionary for counting
diff = {}

# Iterate over rows
for index, row in groupByTable.iterrows():

    # Current row as a tuple
    currentTuple = (row["A"], row["B"])

    # Checking if we have visited the same tuple, but inverted
    if (row["B"], row["A"]) in previousElements:
        
        # As convention, we set the key for the diff dictionary as (smaller_value, larger_value)
        key = (row["B"], row["A"]) if row["B"] <= row["A"] else (row["A"], row["B"])

        # Calculating the diff and storing it in the diff dictionary
        diff[key] = abs(row["size"] - previousElements[(row["B"], row["A"])])

    # If we haven't see this tuple inverted, we store it in the previousElements dictionary  
    else:
        previousElements[currentTuple] = row["size"]

# Now, we transform this dictionary in a pandas dataframe
outputDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "diff"])

for key, value in diff.items():
    outputDF = outputDF.append({'A': key[0], 'B': key[1], 'diff': value}, ignore_index=True)

outputDF.head()
```

The result is the following:

| A | B | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 456 | 1 |
| 113 | 457 | 0 |